# Dockerized Zuul Gateway failing to connect to dockerized Eureka Server

Tags: java, spring, docker, netflix-eureka

I am trying to make docker-compose.yml file from which I should be able to use dockerized Spring boot microservices and connect them to dockerized Eureka registry, but there seems to be the problem with microservices discovering Eureka Server registry, even though my microservices connected before to Eureka server while only running plain .jar applications from Eclipse.

First I tried by dockerizing Eureka server and Zuul gateway. 
When Eureka is dockerized and executed as a container (using docker run -p 8761:8761), it can be accessed by non-docker spring boot application Zuul gateway.

When I dockerize and run as a container Zuul gateway (using docker run -p 8762:8762), it is not recognized on dockerized Eureka server.

Also, since I have realized that the docker network might be a problem, I've decided to use docker-compose file for this, and have tried connecting them using same overlay network, but there seems to be no success once again.

Also, it should be noted that when both Eureka server and Zuul gateway are dockerized and run as containers, both can be accessed from both browser and postman, but they do not see each other.

This is my service-registry (Eureka server) application.properties

```
spring.application.name=service-registry
server.port=8761
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false


eureka.server.wait-time-in-ms-when-sync-empty=0
```

This is my api-gateway (Zuul gateway) relevant application.properties

```
server.port=8762
spring.application.name=api-gateway

#eureka.client.enabled=false

eureka.client.service-url.default-zone=http://service-registry:8761/eureka/
```

This is my Dockerfile for service-registry (Eureka server)

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

ADD /target/service-registry-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar service-registry.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/service-registry.jar"]

EXPOSE 8761
```

This is my Dockerfile for api-gateway (Zuul gateway)

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

ADD target/api-gateway-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar api-gateway.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/api-gateway.jar"]

EXPOSE 8762
```

This is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  service-registry:
    image: ftntim1/xml-booking:service-registry
    ports:
      - "8761:8761"
    networks:
      - megatravel-network

  api-gateway:
    image: ftntim1/xml-booking:api-gateway
    ports:
      - "8762:8762"
    links:
      - service-registry
    depends_on:
      - service-registry
    environment:
        EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICEURL_DEFAULTZONE: http://service-registry:8761/eureka
    networks:
      - megatravel-network

networks:
  megatravel-network:
    driver: overlay
```

Answer (score 4):

As I saw later, it looks like I only needed to switch to camel notation for default zone configuration in application.properties for Zuul proxy.

Before it was:

```
eureka.client.service-url.default-zone = http://service-registry:8761/eureka
```

By switching to:

```
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone = http://service-registry:8761/eureka
```

..it started connecting properly.

Seems like an ambiguous solution, so I would expect from someone experienced in Spring Boot on SO to comment on this situation and thoroughly explain what happened.

Comment: OMG, this worked, I have exact same problem as you. And just changing to cameCase works, WTH

Comment: I looked at docs and apparently it's the camel case - https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi__service_discovery_eureka_clients.html, but the only question is why was it working when running as a standalone application without cameCase, as least SpringBoot must show some sort of error, the read sqiwwly line, for what I understand since it's incorrect parameter springboot ignores it and falls back to the default which should be http://localhost:8761/eureka and hence it keeps on working in ignorance.

Comment: here's the reason - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/19043